# Url_encoding in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Question: How can I change url?

I add anchor tag in wordpress editor to open my file:

```
<a href="www.example.com/ex ex1.pdf" target="_blank">Ex Ex1</a>
```

when I click on Ex Ex1 link then it open my file and link looks like: www.example.com/ex ex1.pdf

But i want to open this link open like: www.example.com/ex%20ex1.pdf

Comment: For best practice, Never use space in your url.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php).

```
<a href="<?php echo rawurlencode(www.example.com/ex ex1.pdf);?>" target="_blank">Ex Ex1</a>
```

But the best practice is not to include files with spaces. Just rename the file to something like ˙`ex_ex1.pdf`